# Declare structure as pointer, possible?

Tags: c

I am not advanced in C, I like Java more. I saw at one of my mates the following code and I'm curious if it is ok, because it wasn't working for him but he said it should work and the error is somewhere else.

```
typedef struct nameOfStruct {
   type1 *elem1;
   type2 *elem2;
   struct nameOfStruct *next;
} *nameOfStruct;
```

So, is it possible to have `*nameOfStruct`, or should it simply be `nameOfStruct`.

Comment: what was the error? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Please do not go down this route. Be explicit in pointers in C. Saves a klot of pain in the long run as people forget they are pointers and need to be freed. C does not have a garbage collector unlink Java.

Answer (score 2):

This is valid C, but it would be incredibly confusing to use (`nameOfStruct` sounds like an object type, but actually it's a pointer).  So avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to answer this without seeing the calling code, but here's what you should know:

`*nameOfStruct` creates an alias for pointer to struct, which is quite missleading as the name doesn't suggest that it is actually a pointer. I wouldn't recommend to use it.

If he want's to use it as a shortcut for `struct nameOfStruct` then drop the extra `*`.

Answer (score 0):

`nameOfStruct` is a pointer to a `struct nameOfStruct`.
`*nameOfStruct` is a pointer to a pointer to a `struct nameOfStruct`.

Both are valid and mean different things, I guess you want to use the first one. You should name your typedef `nameOfStruct_ptr` though, because the name is confusing.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Neither am I. Did I say something wrong? Or some people are in bad mood? I don't get it.